# Silverstripe UploadField upload multiple image but not all at same time

Tags: php, upload, silverstripe

I want to know if there are an extension of UploadField that allow to upload 120 images not all in same time? That cause I/O server issues not responding excessive usage. So how queue images one at time? I dont want to upload images one by one. Modules somewhere or piece of code?

with GridFieldBulkEditingTools added in my projext :

```
private static $many_many = array(
    'Images' => 'Image',
);

...

    $gridFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldSortableRows('SortOrder'));
    $gridFieldConfig->getComponentByType('GridFieldBulkUpload')
        ->setUfSetup('setFolderName', 'Uploads/Images/Rubriques/Galerie')
        ->setUfConfig('sequentialUploads', true);
    $gridfield = new GridFieldBulkUpload("Images", "Images", $this->Images()->sort("SortOrder"), $gridFieldConfig);
```

Results... blank page.

Comment: You can use a Gridfield with the bulkuploader extension https://github.com/colymba/GridFieldBulkEditingTools. I also love https://github.com/colymba/GridFieldGalleryTheme for galleries...

Comment: Can I add to that GridField a has_many or many_many (images)? I have always a blank page into the cms after refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a GridField for managing `has_many` or `many_many` with help of `BulkEditingTools` for uploading a lot of images at once.

I normally make an extra DataObject that holds the Image relation with other information (translated captions, copyright info etc...) like:

```
<?php
class GalleryPic extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Text',
        'Description' => 'Text',
        'Copyright' => 'Text',
        'SortOrder' => 'Int'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Attachment' => 'Image',
        'ResourcePage' => 'Page'
    );

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = new FieldList(
            TextField::create('Title', 'Title'),
            TextareaField::create('Description', 'Desc.'),
            TextField::create('Copyright', 'Copyright / Source'),
            $imageField = UploadField::create('Attachment')
        );
        $imageField->setAllowedFileCategories('image');
        $imageField->setAllowedMaxFileNumber(1);

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Then i have a DataExtension that plugs a `has_many` to any page type or dataobject:

```
<?php

class PageGallery extends DataExtension
{
    private static $has_many = array(
        'Gallery' => 'GalleryPic'
    );

    function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)
    {
        $conf = GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create(10);
        $conf->addComponent(new GridFieldSortableRows('SortOrder'));
        $conf->addComponent(new GridFieldGalleryTheme('Attachment'));
        $conf->addComponent(new GridFieldBulkUpload());
        //set upload folder if folderperroot extension is installed...
        if ($this->owner->hasMethod('getRootFolderName')) {
            $conf->getComponentByType('GridFieldBulkUpload')->setUfSetup('setFolderName', $this->owner->getRootFolderName());
        }
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Bilder", Gridfield::create('Gallery', 'Gallery', $this->owner->Gallery(), $conf));

        return $fields;
    }
```

Add this to your page using the config yml api (e.g. to a class called MyPage):

```
MyPage:
  extensions:
    - 'PageGallery'
```

And you have your gallery upload gridfield in a seperate tab in the CMS.

I think you know how to loop over the `$Gallery` relation in the template.

This modules need to be installed using composer to get the above example working:

- https://github.com/colymba/GridFieldBulkEditingTools
- https://github.com/colymba/GridFieldGalleryTheme
- https://github.com/wernerkrauss/silverstripe-folderperpage (optional)

Comment: I have found a another module to do this : chunkeduploadfield https://github.com/micschk/silverstripe-chunkeduploadfield. Juste change in docs this line  $sizeMB = .05 * 1024 * 1024; // 50 KB in bytes that work very well and It dont crash the server.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise using this module because it handles muliple uploads very well...  I will admit I've not tried 120 items but I'm confident its the best option out there.

https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-dropzone

"The Dropzone module provides FileAttachmentField, a robust HTML5 uploading interfaces for SilverStripe, allowing forms to save file uploads to DataObject instances."

Comment: All Images are uploaded one by one when drag more than 100 images?

Comment: And I dont see the option like 'setFolderName' to drop files into a specific folder.

Comment: Sorry I'm not going into any more specifics, I'm recommending this as the solution to uploading loads of files but in the end the choice is yours.  I'm sorry if this answer is not helpful - if that is the case then please wait for other answers.

Comment: I understand, it's a great try and it's helpful to! But not the best option for my usage. Dont be sorry I appreciate your help

Comment: As this Field subclasses FileField (see https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-dropzone/blob/master/code/FileAttachmentField.php#L9 ) you can use everything FileField has for you... http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-FileField.html